# ZeroMQ to call Julia from Matlab

Tags: matlab, julia, zeromq

I need to call Julia from Matlab:

```
[out1, out2, ...] = jlcall(fname, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Where fname is a string and all other data in a binary format known to both Matlab and Julia.

ZeroMQ implementations exist for [Matlab](https://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/135109368968/using-matlab-with-zeromq) and [Julia](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/ZMQ.jl).

Could you help with a simple ZeroMQ setup which would fit the bill?

Update: following the suggestion of Bill below, I implemented the serialization/deserialization on both sides:

```
% Matlab
>> data = {"sin", 1}
data =
  1×2 cell array
    {'sin'}    {[1]}
>> txt_json = jsonencode(data)
txt_json =
    '["sin",1]'
>> txt_base64 = matlab.net.base64encode(txt_json)
txt_base64 =
    'WyJzaW4iLDFd'

# Julia
julia> JSON3.read(base64decode("WyJzaW4iLDFd"))
2-element JSON3.Array{Any, Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}, Vector{UInt64}}:
  "sin"
 1
julia> f = Symbol(fun)
:sin
julia> @eval $f(arg)
0.8414709848078965
```

How to write the remaining part in ZMQ?

Comment: does the "data in a binary format" change back and forth from string format easily?

Comment: That should not be a problem, base64 exists on both sides. 

The whole task would be in three steps: 1) ZMQ picks up (fname, argx) parts and transmits them to the server. 2) The server reads, processes and generates (outx) 3) ZMQ transmits (outx) parts to the client. 

So it is really about the chain of ZMQ commands. ZMQ doc is partly very prosaic, then you find the atomized bare bones API command lists which obviously changed a lot over different versions.

Comment: You could do a dry run by writing the base64 data to a file and reading it back with the other application.  Once you have that working, you just need a working ZMQ on Matlab or maybe use the Java port with Matlab? Julia's port already exists and could be started with  sock = Socket(REP); bind(sock, "tcp://*:$port)"); message = recv(sock, String); .... send(sock, s);

Comment: Thanks Bill for the guiding hand, please see my update. Could you elaborate with a working ZMQ code?